# Magento 1.9.2.4 patch 8788 && order view adminhtml malformed

Tags: admin, orders, adminhtml

Magento 1.9.2.4 patch 8788 && order view malformed

After running patch 8788 with -R (and first removing uploaderSingle.swf) succesfully we now see an empty order page.

And nothing in logs ...

Anyone run into this one?

[UPDATE] Instead of clicking order 1 I clicked order 2 .. then got this.

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Payment_Transaction::_unserializeField() in /var/www/html/myserver/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php on line 86`

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue unfortunately. Any error in the server logs (not the magento logs) ?

Comment: checking now ..

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Somehow patch had patched files **twice**

Edit
Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php

Check for 2 instances of _unserializeField (if you find 2 functions then compare)

Remove 1 instance of the function _unserializeField

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where orders were squashed to the far left. I found the problem to be in class "div.side-col" in the boxes.css I added display:inline-table to this class. seems to not interfere negatively with all other instances.